# firefox bug with: rowspan + border-collapse + border

Tags: html, css

1. We noticed the bug with border in td + "border-collapse: collapse" + rowspan;
2. This bug is noticed only in firefox; in opera, chrome and IE - everything is ok;
3. here is a screenshot of the problem :[image of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSF3o.png)
4. Please does someone have a solution for this bug? if so help me.
5. i am using firefox 38.6.1.

   Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey i think this is  `border-collapse: collapse;` problem now you set this css as like this

```
#catalog {
    border-collapse: collapse;// remove this line
    border-spacing: 0; // add this line 
    color: #103242;
    font: 12px Tahoma;
}
```

Comment: Rohit Azad, thank you. It works fine :)